# Como pegar imagens na internet através do Java?

Tags: java, http

Sou muito iniciante em Java e preciso pegar algumas imagens da internet para inserir no meu projeto (são 5 imagens). Segue links de exemplo:

- www.tempoagr/tempo/irati/temp1
- www.tempoagr/tempo/irati/temp2
- www.tempoagr/tempo/irati/temp3

Como fazer?

Comment: Você quer baixar as imagens durante a execução do programa
ou baixar agora para inserir a imagem no seu projeto? obs: os links das imagens que você postou não estão disponível (devem estar apenas na sua rede)

Comment: Explique melhor oq vc deseja fazer e poste código também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vê se isso aqui funciona pra voce:

```
URL urlObj = new URL(//img que vc quer baixar.);                                    
HttpURLConnection  httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToSave));
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
} finally {
    try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o código de exemplo abaixo pode te ajudar, caso seu projeto seja "Desktop ou Applet", programado através da API Swing.

O exemplo de código abaixo, irá fazer download do logotipo da Google e irá exibi-lo na tela, através de um componente swing. Que nada mais é uma forma de manipular aplicações gráficas no Java. (Mundo Desktop). Com poucas mudanças você pode adaptá-lo para sua necessidade.

Lembrando que o código abaixo, irá fazer um "preload" da imagem antes de ela ser exibida.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Stackoverflow2673 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // cria frame (janela)
        // seta preferencias do frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(580, 250);

        // inicializa painel
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // inicializa label
        JLabel lblImg = new JLabel(); 

        // inicializa a imagem URL dentro de um objeto ImageIcon
        URL urlImg = new URL("https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
        ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(urlImg);
        // faz o preload da imagem
        while(imgIcon.getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.LOADING); 

        // injeta o icone no label
        lblImg.setIcon(imgIcon);
        // adicina o label no panel
        p.add(lblImg);

        frame.getContentPane().add(p);

        // abre a janela (frame)
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `java.net.URL`, `java.awt.Image` e `javax.imageio.ImageIO`:

```
Url url = new URL("http://www.tempoagr/tempo/irati/temp1");
Image imagem = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Lembre-se que pra isso funcionar a URL deve ser válida, ou uma exceção será "jogada".

Claro, isso é caso você queira pegar a imagem DENTRO do programa. Se for isso, tem muito mais complexidade:

- Tratar a possível exceção caso o link esteja fora do ar
- Caso você esteja usando uma interface gráfica (tipo Swing e JavaFX), pegar a imagem em um novo thread para não bloquear a aplicação até que o download seja concluído

Answer (score 0):

Se você está tentando incluir uma imagem ao seu programa em tempo de design, pode fazer da seguinte maneira no Eclipse:

Crie um *Source Folder* no seu projeto. Clique com o botão direito em `Project` > `New` > `Source Folder`. Copie sua imagem para lá. A partir daí, você pode internamente carregar a imagem da seguinte maneira:

```
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("arquivo.ext");
```

Se você quer fazer isso programaticamente, você tem ao menos duas opções:

Via `javax.imageio`:

```
Image image = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.website.com/arquivo.ext");
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Via `Sockets`/`stream`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.website.com/arquivo.ext");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://arquivo.ext");
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
```

Aproveitando, as URLs que você postou parecem ser locais. Como sugestão, poste em algum serviço de hosting de imagens, como o [Snag.gy](http://snag.gy/).

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver rodando em um sistema operacional Unix like você fazer uma chamada dentro do java utilizando ferramentas de linha de comando do seu sistema.

```
GET http://www.weronline.com/nuno/varios/imagens/teste1.jpg HTTP/1.0 > teste.jpeg
```

ou

```
wget http://www.weronline.com/nuno/varios/imagens/teste1.jpg
```

Ambos comandos irão salvar a imagem do link, porém com o GET vc pode redirecionar a saída de forma mais flexível do que com o wget.

Código exemplo java para executar prograamas de linha de comando:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class testprog {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("GET http://www.weronline.com/nuno/varios/imagens/teste1.jpg HTTP/1.0 > teste.jpeg");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

PS: Exemplo java pego do link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code